# Some of ReSharper settings not visible

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper, code-analysis

I have downloaded ReSharper to Visual Studio 2022. I need to run code analysis to check if all varables are named correctly in camelCase.
Also I want to implement custom rule that no double or float type variables would be used in the project.

There should be an option Code Inspection | Custom Patterns in Extensions -> ReSharper -> Options.

[image: Settings window]

I cannot find this option. How do I configure custom rule and run code analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that my ReSharper was disabled. I had turn on trial version. I didt it clicking on Why is Resharper disabled:

[image]